# Is it possible to use the WebAPIs in VsCode such as WebAudio etc?

Tags: audio, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-code

I'd like to use the awesome WebAPIs which power VsCode/electron. So, is there a way to use VsCode for, say, playing audio from the local disk?

Answer (score 1):

A VSCode extension does not have access to editor's DOM or web specific APIs. Two possible ways to work around this:

- Use the [`previewHtml` command](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api-commands) if you need to create a custom view. This command allows you to hand VSCode an html document to render. Any scripts in the html will not have access to the editor's DOM, but can access their own dom and most web APIs. This approach works well if you are building a custom view or custom UI.
- Call out to an external program to provide this functionality. Since the extension has access to node, to play audio for example, you could spawn a process that invokes `afplay`.

Comment: Ah nice! 
 I found this repo https://github.com/tomi/vscode-js-complexity-analysis/tree/master/src which sort of does what you meant.

 Are there cross-platform version of afplay ( perhaps in rust/go or something? )